# Capturing System.AccessViolationException

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I have a Windows service that crashes in an unhandled way with the exception System.AccessViolationException. I does happen in one of 1000 cases when trying to load a user profile (during impersonation). While I am interested in finding the solution more importantly is that I cannot capture this unhandled error - and terminate my service in a good way.

During start I have added this exeception handler:

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhandledException
```

If I hard code throw System.AccessViolationException as the same place in the code it is captured by my handler. But in the 1 out of 1000 calls the process is terminated and I can only see information about this in the event viewer.

Any ideas how to capture this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
Try
    'your code
Catch ex As AccessViolationException
    'write your ex.ToString() on a file or whatever
End Try
```

Comment: I both capturing general exceptions (ex as Exception) and unhandled like I described above. Still the service crashes. LoadProfile is a call to an unmanaged function (from managed code).